# How does Facebook know the email address is invalid

Tags: php, email

Most of us use regular expressions to decide if email address in form entry is valid or not and then send a link to assure that user has access to this email account .. while browsing Facebook with an alternative account I got this pop up message
[image: Email no longer Valid]

the message says that email address is no longer valid .. how does Facebook know this .. does it use mail delivery reports to get the state of the email address ? .. any idea how to do this in PHP ?

Comment: The Yahoo! mail service is likely reporting that the mail cannot be delivered. This is handled at the mail-transport level, and requires that a MTA actually cares to provide a sufficient error indicator. Otherwise, the only way to tell is lack of a "positive reply" - but no replies does not imply invalid.

Comment: See http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/smtpreplies.html for some ideas of what *might* be reported